# JQuery Ui Resizable Used to work in older version, no longer in new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have an issue with this, when you stretch the red rectangle to the right, it goes from 20 to 100 in 40 intervals, 20-60-100.. and then when you shrink it it goes back correctly, 100-60-20 but the black rectangle, that stretches to the left instead, goes correctly 20-60-100 but when its time to shrink it, it fails as it goes 100-60-40 and not back to 20, it works on a prior version, is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? here are examples of both the working and not working versions.

**Older version jquery ui (v1.10.1) WORKING:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#demo").resizable({
    handles: 'e',
    grid: [40, 0],
    minWidth: 20,
    maxWidth:100,
    stop:function( event, ui ) {
      $('#res1').text($(this).width());
    }
  });
  
  $("#demo2").resizable({
    handles: 'w',
    grid: [40, 0],
    minWidth: 20,
    maxWidth:100,
    stop:function( event, ui ) {
      $('#res2').text($(this).width());
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.row{
  padding:20px;  
}

#demo {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #F00;
  left: 100px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#FFF
}

#demo2 {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  left: 100px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#FFF
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
<div id="demo"></div><span id="res1">20</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div id="demo2"></div><span id="res2">20</span>
</div>
```

**New version jquery ui (v1.11.4) NOT WORKING:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#demo").resizable({
    handles: 'e',
    grid: [40, 0],
    minWidth: 20,
    maxWidth:100,
    stop:function( event, ui ) {
      $('#res1').text($(this).width());
    }
  });
  
  $("#demo2").resizable({
    handles: 'w',
    grid: [40, 0],
    minWidth: 20,
    maxWidth:100,
    stop:function( event, ui ) {
      $('#res2').text($(this).width());
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.row{
  padding:20px;  
}

#demo {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #F00;
  left: 100px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#FFF
}

#demo2 {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  left: 100px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#FFF
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
<div id="demo"></div><span id="res1">20</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div id="demo2"></div><span id="res2">20</span>
</div>
```

Comment: wow looks like you may need to log this with jQuery team nice find